# Read a value on a particular line in a text file and use it in bash

Tags: macos, bash, unix, text

I have a computation which generates an output.txt file continuously.
Once the computation is over, I need to read (using a bash script) an particular value and then use it elsewhere in my script.
For instance, my output.txt ends like this:

```
1.980000e+01 1.527115e-01 3.596175e+01 -8.044004e-02 0.000000e+00-0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00 8 2185 3351
    2.000000e+01 3.568107e-01 3.489784e+01 -7.459970e-02 0.000000e+00 -0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00 21 2183 3351
    extract 
    fg number=1069 
    number of g in each w=75 
    'end reached !'
    2.000040e+01 0.000000e+00 -0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00 -0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00 0 1907 2987
```

I need to get the value 1069 (the so-called "fg number").

Can someone tell me how I can read and echo this value using bash?

Thank you all :)

PS: alors, if the string "fg number=" already appears above in the .txt file, how can I get the value given by its last appearance?

Answer (score 3):

If you have GNU grep:

```
grep -oP '(?<=fg number=)\d+' output.txt | tail -n 1
```

Ah, osx. Lets try awk:

```
awk -F"=" '$1 ~ /fg number$/ {value=$2} END {print value}' output.txt
```

If it's a huge file, might help to read it from the bottom:

```
tac output.txt | awk -F"=" '$1 ~ /fg number$/ {print $2; exit}'
```

I don't know if `tac` is available on the mac.

Comment: Thanks, tac does not seem to exist on MacOs (please correct me if I'm wrong).
I used:
myvalue=$(awk -F"=" '$1 ~ /free grain number$/ {value=$2} END {print value}' $file)
to load the result into a variable and use it elsewhere ;)
thanks again!

Comment: I found this to install tac on Mac OS X: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/114041/how-can-i-get-the-tac-command-on-os-x In fact, we can use tail with the option -r instead ;)

Comment: To install tac using Homebrew: <brew install coreutils>
and then <ln -s /usr/local/bin/gtac /usr/local/bin/tac>

Comment: Note that you can easily run `tac`, `rev` and `shuf` which are otherwise unavailable under `macOS` with docker like this `docker run -i busybox:latest tac  < SomeMacFile`

Answer (score 1):

Using `sed`:

```
% sed -n 's/^[[:blank:]]*fg number=\([[:digit:]]*\).*/\1/p' file.txt
1069
```

If you want the last one from multiple:

```
% sed -n 's/^[[:blank:]]*fg number=\([[:digit:]]*\).*/\1/p' file.txt | tail -1
1069
```

Answer (score 1):

In Bash:

```
regex='fg number=([[:digit:]]+)'

while read line; do
    if [[ "$line" =~ $regex ]]; then
        echo "fg number is ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
        break   # Remove if using cat instead of tac
    fi
done < <(tac infile)    # Use cat if tac is not available
```

This reads the input file starting with the last line (`tac` starts at the end) and tries to match each line with the regex, stopping once it does. The capture group is then in `${BASH_REMATCH[1]}`.

If `tac` is not available, it can either be made available through [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/), or the whole file has to be processed with `cat`, see comments.

Comment: @LeChat See update. Other people's one-liners are of course much more concise than all this.